# How would I batch rename a lot of files using command-line?

Tags: server, windows, file-sharing, rename, batch-rename

I have a problem which I am unable to solve: I need to rename a great dump of files using patterns. I tried using [this](http://tips.webdesign10.com/how-to-bulk-rename-files-in-linux-in-the-terminal), but I always get an error.

I have a folder, inside with a **lot** of files. Running `ls -1 | wc -l`, it returns that I have like 160000 files inside. The problem is, that I wish to move these files to a Windows system, but most of them have characters like `:` and `?` in them, which makes the file unaccessible on said Windows-based systems.

(As a *"do not solve but deal with"* method, I tried booting up a LiveCD on the Windows system and moving the files using the live OS. Under that Ubuntu, the files were readable and writable on the mounted NTFS partition, but when I booted back on Windows, it showed that the file is there but Windows was unable to access it in any fashion: rename, delete or open.)

I tried running `rename 's/\:/_' *` inside the folder, but I got *Argument list too long* error. Some search revealed that it happens because I have so many files, and then I arrived [here](http://www.techexpertblog.com/linux-rename-long-list-of-files). The problem is that I don't know how to alter the command to suit my needs, as I always end up having various errors like

- Trying `find -name '*:*' | xargs rename : _`, it gives *xargs: unmatched single quote; by default quotes are special to xargs unless you use the -0 option [\n] syntax error at (eval 1) line 1, near ":" [\n] xargs: rename: exited with status 255; aborting*
- Adding the `-0` after `xargs` turns the error message to *xargs: argument line too long*

These files are archive files generated by various PHP scripts. The best solution would be having a chance to rename them **before** they are moved to Windows, but if there is no way to do it, we might have a way to rename the files **while** they are moved to Windows. I use `samba` and `proftpd` to move the files.

Unfortunately, graphical software are out of the question as the server containing the files is what it is, a server, with only command-line interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using find's -exec should work, though it'll recurse through subdirectories, which in turn will fail if any of the subdirectories happen to contain `:` or `?`.

```
find . -name "*[:?]*" -exec rename 'y/:?/__/' {} +
```

The `argument list too long` error you get because the `*` gets expanded to all 160k files in the directory, which exceeds the maximum argument length on your system.

```
$ getconf ARG_MAX
2097152
```

160k filenames may easily exceed 2MiB. You can work past this by either renaming one file at a time

```
for file in ./*[:?]*; do 
    mv "$file" "${file//[:?]/_}"
done
```

or fill an array and process them in chunks. How large the chunk could be depends on the average length of the filenames and the ARG_MAX value; or just set a low enough value to be safe, e.g. 1000:

```
files=( ./*[:?]* ) n=${#files[@]}
size=1000
for (( i=0; i<n; i+=size )); do
    rename 'y/:?/__/' "${files[@]:i:size}"
done
```

Also see [BashFAQ 30](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/030).

Comment: find can be asked to NOT recurse by using `-maxdepth 1`. This will operate only on files on the current directory. Also, for the files containing `?`, it will have to be escaped, e.g. `find -name "*\?*"`. The original poster didn't mention if he cared about subdirectories; if not, the `find` solution seems like the best one.

Comment: @roadmr, sure, though I'd rather use shell globs or find's `-prune` than the non-standard `-maxdepth`, but that's mainly because I don't work with only GNU/linux systems. And right, I forgot about `?`, I'll update the answer to include replacing `?`.

Comment: @roadmr Negative, the whole banch of files are in the same subfolder. I will look into that FAQ article later, for now, the code in the middle (`for file in`...) is started to run, we will see how it turns out. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I use this for mass renaming: `vidir`. It uses more or less the same syntax us `vi` does!

```
apt-get install moreutils
```

Go to the directory with the 160k files

```
cd dir
```

Launch vidir

```
vidir
```

Next replace all : in the filename with e.g -

```
: % s/:/-/g
```

Do the same with other strange characters like ?

```
: % s/?/-/g
```

Now save the files, with :w

vidir allows editing of the contents of a directory in a text editor.

http://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/